# Pandas count number of trades by month

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have a dataframe with signals to enter/exit a trade in column `long`, and the index is date. `long` looks something like this (True value means you hold a position, False means you no longer hold a position):

```
2010-01-04    False
2010-01-05    False
2010-01-06    False
2010-01-07    False
2010-01-08    False
2010-01-11    False
2010-01-12    False
2010-01-13    False
2010-01-14     True
2010-01-15     True
2010-01-19     True
2010-01-20     True
2010-01-21     True
2010-01-22     True
2010-01-25     True
2010-01-26     True
2010-01-27     True
2010-01-28     True
2010-01-29     True
2010-02-01     True
2010-02-02     True
2010-02-03     True
2010-02-04     True
2010-02-05     True
2010-02-08     True
2010-02-09     False
2010-02-10     True
2010-02-11     True
2010-02-12     False
2010-02-16     False
```

So for my data I should get an output like

```
2010-01 1
2010-02 1
```

1 in Jan since we entered a trade in January and held it through out the entire rest of the month, and 1 in Feb since we exited our Jan trade (which doesn't count as a new trade) but one day later we did enter into a new trade (assume we did nothing for the rest of the month

I have the following code to count the number of changes in allocation, but I have no clue how to efficiently split the count of new trades by month

```
longs = (df.long-df.long.shift()).ne(0)
```

in this case longs = 4, so dividing by 2 (every two 'ticks' represent the lifecycle of a trade) will give me the effective number of trades

How can I count the number of trades started by month?

Comment: So for January it's a `1` because you started a Trade and it's true for the rest of the month, but the same doesn't seem to be True for February, it seems that the last data in February is False.  What's the rule?  Is it just how many trades *start* in a month?

Comment: yes, in feb we entered a trade on the 10th and exited two days later, doing nothing for the rest of the month, hence the trade count for feb is 1 (I didn't want to have a massive example, that's why I said assume they're all false after feb 16th). So yes, how many trades started in that month

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can check how many times you go from `False` to `True` in a month using:

```
s = (df.long & ~df.long.shift().fillna(False)).astype(int)
```

Then just groupby and sum:

```
s.groupby(pd.Grouper(freq='MS')).sum()

2010-01-01    1
2010-02-01    1
Freq: MS, Name: flag, dtype: int32
```

Comment: I get AttributeError: 'DataFrame' object has no attribute 'date'

Comment: You didn't supply your column names, replace `date` with whatever the name of your date column is.  Is it your index?

Comment: it's the index :)

Comment: did it for you, tests looks fine :)